# Android Application to Discover Nearby iPhone Devices

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing an Android Application where in I display the nearby iPhone devices. I have used the standard Android Bluetooth API's as well as Android Bluetooth LE API's for scanning the nearby iPhones. But I am unable to get the list of iPhones.

**Note:**

1. I see that the Settings Application present in the Stock Android is able to display all the devices.
2. Target Android OS - Marshmallow.

I am a newbie to Android. Kindly elaborate the answers for my better understanding. I have checked other links on Google and was not getting my desired result.

**Standard Android Bluetooth Scan/discover(Scan and displays nearby devices but not an iPhone)**

```
private void displayListOfFoundDevices(){

arrayOfFoundBTDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothObject>();

// start looking for bluetooth devices
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

// Discover new devices
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            // Get the bluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Get the "RSSI" to get the signal strength as integer,
            // but should be displayed in "dBm" units
            int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);

            // Create the device object and add it to the arrayList of devices
            BluetoothObject bluetoothObject = new BluetoothObject();
            bluetoothObject.setBluetooth_name(device.getName());
            bluetoothObject.setBluetooth_address(device.getAddress());
            bluetoothObject.setBluetooth_state(device.getBondState());
            bluetoothObject.setBluetooth_type(device.getType());    // requires API 18 or higher
            bluetoothObject.setBluetooth_uuids(device.getUuids());
            bluetoothObject.setBluetooth_rssi(rssi);

            arrayOfFoundBTDevices.add(bluetoothObject);

            // 1. Pass context and data to the custom adapter
            FoundBTDevicesAdapter adapter = new FoundBTDevicesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayOfFoundBTDevices);

            // 2. setListAdapter
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);  }
```

**BluetoothLE Code snippet(Scan and displays nearby devices but not an iPhone)**

```
    btManager =(BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
    btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


    if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
        builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.i("Main","Scan Result: Add: " +result.getDevice().getAddress());
        peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName()+ " add: " + result.getDevice().getAddress() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n");

        // auto scroll for text view
        final int scrollAmount = peripheralTextView.getLayout().getLineTop(peripheralTextView.getLineCount()) - peripheralTextView.getHeight();
        // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
        if (scrollAmount > 0)
            peripheralTextView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide what did you try, code snippets and/or console output.

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Kindly find the code snippets attached.